# Why won't Javascript code work after moving it from html to an external js file?

Tags: javascript, html, inline-code

I have this Javascript code that was working perfectly fine in my HTML. When I moved it to my main.js it suddenly stopped working.

**Disclaimer: I am very new to jQuery and Javascript, so sorry if it is really obvious.**

```
var infoVisible = false,
buyVisible = false;

function closeAllProductInfo() {
    $('#info').css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    $('#buy').css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    $('#options.info a').removeClass('active');
    $('#options.buy a').removeClass('active');
    infoVisible = false;
    buyVisible = false;
    imagesVisible = false;
}

function openProductInfo() {
    closeAllProductInfo();
    $('#info').css({visibility: 'visible', opacity: 0});
    $('#info').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    $('#options.info a').addClass('active');
    infoVisible = true;
}

function openProductBuy() {
    closeAllProductInfo();
    $('#buy').css({visibility: 'visible', opacity: 0});
    $('#buy').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    $('#options.buy a').addClass('active');
    buyVisible = true;
}

$('.info').click(function() {
    if (infoVisible) { 
        $('#info').animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function() {  
            closeAllProductInfo(); 
        }); 
    } else { 
        openProductInfo(); 
    }

    return false;
});

$('.buy').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('in-active')) {
        if (buyVisible) { 
            $('#buy').animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function() { 
                closeAllProductInfo(); 
            }); 
        } 
        else { 
            openProductBuy(); 
        }
    }

    return false;
});

$('#info').click(function() {
    if (infoVisible) { 
        $('#info').animate({opacity:0}, 250, function() { 
            closeAllProductInfo(); 
        }); 
    }
});

$('#buy').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('in-active')) {
        if (buyVisible) { 
            $('#buy').animate({opacity:0}, 250, function() { 
                closeAllProductInfo(); 
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your html code for integrating this file, and jquery?

Comment: Even if it does not have anything to do with your actual code, please format it properly. It's hard to read. Also show us how you are including the file.

Comment: In what way did it stop working? How are you including your code in the html?

Comment: Sorry guys, just figured out its because I was including main.js at the top of the html file. Moved it to the bottom and it works.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr: Good. You cannot access DOM elements if they don't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it used to execute after the document was loaded but now it executes when the script is loaded.  Do you load main.js at the end of your HTML file or the start?  Use this to get it to execute after the document is ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

Comment: That exactly what it was. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, just mark it as the answer to help the next person who has this same question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap all your code in  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code in here.
});
```